# How do I store strings inside of .txt files while not clearing what is already in that file java

Tags: java, string, file, variables

What I currently have is this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.acl.NotOwnerException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      try{
    System.out.print("Enter username: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String username = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter email: ");
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String email = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter password: ");
    Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String password = scanner.nextLine();


    // Create file 
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("username.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write(username + ":" + email + ":" + password);
    //Close the output stream
    out.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

But it keeps clearing the first line. Is there a way I can just get it to add a line each time instead of clearing the first one? If so can someone please help me. I am using repl.it for java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append text to an existing file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open File with append flag as true.

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("username.txt",true);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write("\n" + username + ":" + email + ":" + password);
```

This will ensure that, content in the file in appended. Also, "\n" will ensure that each line is printed on new line in file.

Comment: What does appended mean?

Comment: @SpeedySapphire What does appended mean? If you don't know the meaning of append, then it will better to first learn the meaning of words, then go for writing codes.

Comment: @Bahramdun Adil Jezz I just wanted to know what it meant. Not for someone to tell me not to code.

Comment: @SpeedySapphire Appended means that new username, email and password will be added to file without replacing earlier values.

Comment: @SpeedySapphire Such kind of questions means that it can be very very hard for someone who wants to code if don't the meaning of append. Append mean just append nothing else, so no possible to someone can tell what does append mean.

Comment: ``"\n"`` is not necessary a good idea. It is OP dependent. It will not give the expected result on windows based OS. `System.lineSeparator()` is better.

Comment: @davidxxx Where would you put that

Comment: `out.write(System.lineSeparator() + username + ":" + email + ":" + password);`